# The div content script problem on the other page when the button is pressed

Tags: javascript

```
$("#maincont<?php echo $forwardInterviews; ?>").load("/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/buttonClickDetails.php",
```

When the button is pressed, I bring the content. JSs are missing when fetching the content. JSs appear in the footer in the source code. But the selectpicker property in buttonClickDetails.php does not work.

When I include buttonClickDetails.php as below, selectpicker does not work.

```
<script src="<?php echo url()."assets/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"; ?>"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Based on your code you can't run PHP code from a button click.  You need ajax for that.

Comment: I changed the loading part to ajax.  But the selecpicker script on the page does not work

Comment: I will need to see some code before I can make any suggestions.  HTML, Javascript and PHP.  Just add it to the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the selecpicker class in the div that I called with Ajax. But since I did not renew the selecpicker after calling it, the script was not working.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

My problem was solved with the code.